# How to union 3D region to calculate volume?

Tags: regions, computational-geometry, opencascade

I have a Teapot likes:

```
region = RepairMesh[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "UtahTeapot"}, "MeshRegion"]]
```

[image]

I want to **calculate the volume of it**, but it just `2` dimension as this code:

```
RegionDimension[region]
```

> 2

So I have to fill it into 3D.

```
com = ConnectedMeshComponents[region];
boundmesh = BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[#], MeshCells[#, 2]] & /@ com
RegionDimension /@ boundmesh
```

[image]

Note that these sections have **overlapping parts**:

```
Show[RegionPlot3D[First[boundmesh], PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.4], Red]], 
 RegionPlot3D[#, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue]] & /@ Rest[boundmesh], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

So let's union it, but I get an error information:

```
RegionUnion @@ boundmesh
```

[image]

It is a bug? And how to union all parts to calculate the volume of this tea-pot?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use OpenCascadeLink for that. Convert the pieces you have into a boundary element mesh, convert those to OpenCascade, make the union and convert back:

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
elms = com[[#]]["MakeRepresentation"["ElementMesh"]] & /@ 
   Range[Length[com]];
shapes = OpenCascadeShape /@ elms;
union = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[shapes];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[union];
Volume[BoundaryMeshRegion[bmesh]]

0.37979
```

Comment: What a Magical Grammar....

Comment: Funny, why does the [same input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxIEV.png) gets a different result...

Comment: @yode, I am not sure this is the same input. The boundary ElementMesh of region can not be converted to a BoundaryMeshRegion, because it's not a closed region - that's what you need the union in the first place, not?

Comment: I would like to ask you an additional question if I don't use `ConnectedMeshComponents` to generate that `com` for you. Now you only have that `region`. Can you get the finally result by it? I've tried for a long time but I can't

Comment: @yode, I don't think you can. Why do you need this?