# How do I calculate volume of a polyhedron knowing a list of vertices of polyhedron?

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a list of vertices

```
a = {1/2, 1/2, 0};
b = {-1/2, 1/2, 0};
c = {-1/2, -1/2, 0};
e = {-1/4, 1/4, Sqrt[15]/4};
f = {1/4, -1/4, Sqrt[15]/4};
```

I want to find volume of the tetrahedron `abcef`. I see [this answer](https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/236412-How-Do-I-Calculate-Volume-Of-A-Polyhedron?reply=reply)  and tried

```
a = {1/2, 1/2, 0};
b = {-1/2, 1/2, 0};
c = {-1/2, -1/2, 0};
e = {-1/4, 1/4, Sqrt[15]/4};
f = {1/4, -1/4, Sqrt[15]/4};
Volume[Tetrahedron[{{a, c, e, f}}]] + 
 Volume[Tetrahedron[{{a, b, e, c}}]]
```

and got `Sqrt[5/3]/4`. Is there a way to find volume of a  `{a,b,c,e,f}` directly without calculating sum of two Tetrahedrons?

Comment: In general the volume is indeterminate.  Your reference is a tiny example where the polyhedron is convex, which determines the polyhedron.  But if it might not be convex, or might be disconnected, or not simply connected, then you need a richer description, such as simplicial decomposition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
Volume[Tetrahedron[{{a, c, e, f}, {a, b, e, c}}]]
(*Sqrt[5/3]/4*)
```

Comment: The data given in the question are *five* points.  Ordinarily they won't determine a tetrahedron (despite what the OP writes).  Moreover, it takes some analysis to triangulate the polyhedron, as you seem to do here, even when it is unambiguously specified.

Comment: `Tetrahedron` works with a set of 4-point sublists(collection of tetrahedrons): `Tetrahedron[{{Subscript[p, 1,1],Subscript[p, 1,2],Subscript[p, 1,3],Subscript[p, 1,4]},{Subscript[p, 2,1],\[Ellipsis]},\[Ellipsis]}]https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265156/how-to-union-3d-region-to-calculate-volume?rq=1
represents a collection of tetrahedra.`

Comment: Right: that's because the tetrahedron is convex.  And, in general, there will be a formula for the volume of the convex hull of any set of points.  The problem is that most sets of five or more points do not unique determine a polyhedron, nor is it the case that those multiple possible polyhedra always have the same volume.

Comment: The collection of tetrahedrons may be nonconvex and the volume evaluates correctly too!

Comment: Yes: but representing a polyhedron as a "collection of tetrahedra," *aka* triangulating, requires more information than just the set of its vertices.  That's the whole point.

Comment: @whuber The union of a set of tetrahedrons is well defined, the associated volume too.

Comment: Yes -- assuming they are disjoint.  But -- for the last time -- I will point out that *the set of vertices does not determine the triangulation.*  This should be evident even in two dimensions.

Comment: @whuber Who said that?

Comment: See the first line of the question.